# How to get hair particles to face camera (billboard)?

Tags: particles, constraints

I'm trying to do simple trees:

[image]

I created a plane which then has a track to constraint to it which points at the camera, and that works fine.

[image]

But all my particles still face the same direction. They don't all face the camera. If I move the camera, the original one moves to face the camera, and the particles all move by the same amount.

How do I make them all track to the camera individually?

(also not sure why the angle is weird, I'd prefer to make them always stick straight up)

[image]

**EDIT**

[image]

Here is an edit of the below .blend where I tried to do it myself:
[image]

Notice the above platforms trees dont follow the camera properly. If you change the particle system from "badtrees" to "goodtrees" it works fine. They seems to have identical settings to me.

My process:

- add a new ground plane
- adding particle system to plane
- change to hair
- render as object
- instance object tree
- check off object rotation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two things:

1. The Render Object that you are using needs the Track To Constraint, not the Plane with the Hair.  Although perhaps this is what you did and your question muddies this in your explanation;
2. In Render as, you need to check Object Rotation

   [image]
3. Enable Advanced Hair that allows you to play with Rotation, but it
   is not needed here.  I just want to point this out:

   [image]

Here is an example [image]

[image]

Again with your edited file:

[image]

Comment: Yes I add the track to constraint to the "tree" plane, and have the rotation checked. I tried again from scratch and got the same problem as the first time, though your example looks fine. Even If I try to do it in your file by adding a new ground plane > adding particle system > change to hair > render as object > instance object tree > check off object rotation, it still doesn't work and looks like my images above. Am I missing a step?

Comment: It seems like they're rotating the opposite direction they're supposed to when rotating the camera

Comment: added a gif and blend file download to my post

Comment: @stackers -- Actually it looks like you *do* need to also use "Advanced" Hair, enable rotation and set to None.  Sometimes you just gotta play with these things.  I guess I used Advanced, and then disabled and had the same result and so put this as my "other info".  I have edited my answer.

Comment: Yup, that finally solved it, thanks for your help.